# What is the best practice using Dynamically generated forms or html imput tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Im doing a form where multiple tags appear when certain conditions in the request met, I wonder whether using jQuery to dynamically generate new HTML input tags, or doing all the HTML tags I need in the .jsp file. The first option means making a bigger .js file, the last means making a bigger .jsp file. Are there any advantages of one against the other?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends.**

The main advantage to doing it server-side (`jsp` in your case) is that your forms remain accessible if the user has turned off javascript or your javascript is broken.

Integrations tests which test your forms will also run faster if you do not need to run a (headless) browser with a full javascript runtime.

However, [single-page applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) are by nature javascript-heavy. The server often only serves a simple html skeleton which is then populated by javascript. An advantage to this approach is that web apps can be made to feel very responsive since there is a minimal document and the user can start interacting which the page even as it loads.